# Format string number

Tags: java

I have a string number which is an amount variable I want to format it with commas such that 1000 returns 1,000 and 1000.00 returns exactly 1,000.00 and 1000.000 also returns 1,000.00 at max 2 decimals but if there are no decimals then it should not return any decimals:
Ex: 1000 -> 1,000
1000.00 -> 1,000.00

Comment: Please know I need the code in springboot

Comment: My code uses DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern:#,###.##)
and I use formatter.format(value)
It gives 1,000 for 1000.00 but I need 1,000.00

Comment: Programming questions are out of scope.However, you should, either change your systems locale or specify the locale that should be used.

Comment: I don't think what you want to do is possible, since the input to `DecimalFormat` is not a string, it is a number that will not distinguish between `1000` and `1000.00`. If you always want two decimals to show up, use the pattern `#,###.00`.

Comment: `but if there are no decimals then it should not return any decimals: Ex: 1000 -> 1,000 1000.00 -> 1,000.00` yeah, in that case you would probably need to stick with String (and some ugly pattern matching and manipulation) if you insist. Or maybe "manually" pad the zeroes back based on the original String after the "normal" formation, meh.

Comment: Are the incoming decimals always zero? If you get 1000.015, do you want it rounded, and if so, up or down?

Comment: Elaborating on what @TomYan has said I would parse into a `BigDecimal` since it keeps track of how many decimals were in the input. Then use some logic to distinguish the cases where the scale is 0 or greater, it is -1 (meaning there was exactly one decimal) and the case where it is -2 or less to choose the format to use for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use polymorphism for this: you can have an *Amount* base class and then two derivatives for showing the value with or without the commas. This is  very basic example, you can make it better and find better names:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public abstract class Amount {
    protected final BigDecimal value;

    // very lite "factory" pattern
    public static Amount of(String value) {
        if (value.contains(",")) {
            return new AmountWithComma(value);
            //ps: find better names here
        }
        return new AmountWithoutComma(value);
    }

    public BigDecimal value() {
        return value;
    }

    public abstract String display();
}
```

And now, the derivatives - you can keep them as inner classes (or just package protected classes) and "hide" them from the rest of the project:

```java
static class AmountWithComma extends Amount {
    AmountWithComma(String value) {
        super(new BigDecimal(value.replaceAll(",", "")));
    }

    @Override
    public String display() {
        return value.setScale(2).toString();
    }
}


static class AmountWithoutComma extends Amount {

    private final DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

    AmountWithoutComma(String value) {
        super(new BigDecimal(value));
    }

    @Override
    public String display() {
        return decimalFormat.format(value.doubleValue());
    }
}
```

Now, you can use it like this:

```java
@Test
void test() {
    assertThat(Amount.of("1,000").display())
            .isEqualTo("1,000.00");
    
    assertThat(Amount.of("1000").display())
            .isEqualTo("1000.00");
}
```

Furthermore, you can always use the `amount.value()` accessor to get back the value as a *BigDecimal* so you can potentially pass this object around instead of passing a String and always parse or format it.

Comment: You can.I frankly tend to find polymorphism unsuited or at least not needed for the use case.

Comment: it depends on the context and if this logic of choosing the appropriate format keeps repeating. Ayways, I would avoid putting it into a utility class/function and I would rather encapsulate it inside the `Amount` class itself (regardless if it's done with polymorphism or a smile if)

Comment: The way I read the question, 1000.0 with one decimal is also possible. Does your class hierarchy handle that correctly?